# Sanity check - localizations are pushouts and they are pushout stable

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, localization

Want to make sure I'm not hallucinating. Rings and algebras are commutative and unitary. Let $k$ be a ring and $A$ a $k$-algebra. Let $f\in A$, and identify $f\in A$ with the arrow $k[x]\to A$ which maps $x\in k[x]$ to $f$. Then the square below is a pushout in the category of $k$-algebras.

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} k[x]  @>>> k[x,x^{-1}] \\ @V{f}VV @VVV\\ A @>>> A_f \end{CD}$$

Is this correct?

Along this line, by pushout pasting and then dualizing, basic affines are pullback stable. Is this also correct?

Comment: Can you show that $M \otimes_A A_f \cong M_f$ for some $A$-module $M$?

Comment: @user251222 I'm not sure I understand why this is related to the question, but using the universal property of tensor products and the concrete constructions of $A_f,M_f$ with fractions, I can prove $(m,\frac rs)\mapsto \frac{rm}s$ is the inverse of $\frac ms\mapsto m\otimes_A\frac 1s$... Incidentally, is there a slicker proof?

Comment: The point of my comment is that tensor products of algebras can be constructed by taking tensor products of the underlying module and finding a reasonable algebra structure. The obvious algebra structure here works. Since $f$ takes $x$ to an element in $A$ in the left- vertical arrow and the top right arrow inverts $x$, you are forcing this element in $A$ to be inverted in the pushout.

Comment: @user251222 that was the reasoning which led me to believe this square is a pushout, but I don't think there's any need to refer to tensor products or modules - clearly an arrow out of $k[x,x^{-1}]$ amounts to picking an invertible element. Am I right in saying this square is a pushout in the category of $k$-algebras?

Comment: No, you are taking a pushout of $k[x]$-algebras. Pushouts of algebras are given by the tensor product. If you know anything about schemes, then this corresponds to the pullback.

Comment: @user251222 sorry, I'm still confused. Are you saying the square is a pushout in the category of $k[x]$-algebras? We can look at $k[x,x^{-1}]$ as the localization $k[x]_x$ which fits in with your tensor product point of view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47284/discussion-between-user251222-and-arrow).

Comment: @user251222 colimits in under-categories are computed by colimits in the ambient category. in particular, the diagram in question is a pushout in each of: the category of rings, the category of $k$-algebras, the category of $k[x]$-algebras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly right. There's (at least) 2 ways to show this.

1. Show that any morphism of rings factors uniquely as a localization followed by a conservative morphism (a morphism $R\xrightarrow{f}R'$ is conservative if $f(r)$ invertible implies $r$ is invertible). This would imply that you have an orthogonal factorization system whose left class is the class of localizations and right class is the class of conservative morphisms. Since left classes of factorization systems are stable under pushouts, the claim follows.
2. Show that the pushout of the quotient $R\to R/f$ with $R\to S$ is zero if and only if $R\to S$ factors through the localization $R\to R_f$. In the language of affine schemes this means that principal open embeddings are complements to hypersurfaces. Since pullbacks of hypersurfaces are hypersurfaces (i.e. pushouts of quotients by a single element are quotient by a single element), it then suffices to check that, in any category, if a morphism has a complement and a pullback, the pullback of the complement and the complement of the pullback satisfy the same universal property.